# How to merge multiples MongoDB documents into one?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm working with a collection of measurements that I continuously receive from an IoT Device. Each measurement has the following document schema:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58e3c885713c09001a0c2125"),
    "recvTime" : ISODate("2017-04-18T16:23:38.928Z"),
    "entityId" : "t01",
    "entityType" : "Thing",
    "attrName" : "Temperature",
    "attrType" : "text",
    "attrValue" : "32.5"
}
```

According to how the device is programmed, for each attribute of the device I have a different measurement. As the device sends data every N seconds, every N seconds are inserted as many documents as attributes in my device. All document with the same timeinstant in "recvTime" field.

My problem is that I want to collapse all the measurement data corresponding to a specific time in a single document. This way I would have a document with all device measurements every N seconds instead of as many documents as attributes on my device.

For example, with two attributes **temperature** and **preassure** I want to transform this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58e3c885713c09001a0c2125"),
    "recvTime" : ISODate("2017-04-18T16:23:38.928Z"),
    "entityId" : "t01",
    "entityType" : "Thing",
    "attrName" : "Temperature",
    "attrType" : "text",
    "attrValue" : "32.5"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58e3c885713c09001a0c2125"),
    "recvTime" : ISODate("2017-04-18T16:23:38.928Z"),
    "entityId" : "t01",
    "entityType" : "Thing",
    "attrName" : "Preassure",
    "attrType" : "text",
    "attrValue" : "512"
}
```

into something like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58e3c885713c09001a0c2125"),
    "recvTime" : ISODate("2017-04-18T16:23:38.928Z"),
    "entityId" : "t01",
    "entityType" : "Thing",
    "Temperature" : "32.5",
    "Preassure" : "512"
}
```

Is there a way to do this using only query with Mongo Aggregation Framework? I would prefer not to have to do it within an application.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below aggregation in 3.6.

[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) to group all the same timestamp documents with `$$ROOT` to `$push` the complete document.

[`$objectToArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) with [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) to filter the keys required to be renamed followed by [`$mergeObjects`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects/#exp._S_mergeObjects) with [`$arrayToObject`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/) in a [`$reduce`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/) operator to merge grouped documents.

[`$replaceRoot`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) to promote the merged document to top level.

```
[{"$group":{
   "_id":"$recvTime",
   "data":{"$push":"$$ROOT"}
}},
{"$replaceRoot":{
   "newRoot":{
     "$reduce":{
       "input":"$data",
       "initialValue":{},
       "in":{
         "$mergeObjects":[
           {"$arrayToObject":{
             "$filter":{
               "input":{"$objectToArray":"$$this"},
               "cond":{"$not":{"$in":["$$this.k",["attrName","attrValue","attrType"]]}}
             }
           }},
           {"$arrayToObject":[[{"k":"$$this.attrName","v":"$$this.attrValue"}]]},
           "$$value"
           ]
       }
     }
   }
}}]
```

Comment: Thanks you! I will try your suggestion,